# SharePoint Online Storage and Back Up Costs

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are looking at moving our SharePoint on premises environment into the cloud.
I have been enquiring about storage costs for SharePoint on Line and generally the answer seems to be  it is free once you have paid the licence fees. However want to double check that surely it can’t be unlimited – does anyone have any info on this - sometimes the answers had referenced One Drive limits but most of our data is in shared documents libraries.

Also if we want incremental backups does anyone have ball park figures of what the charges might be?
Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

This answer varies depending on your subscription location (your country) and the type of subscription (if you are a commercial private company, a government org (public sector), an education sector org or a charity, note that there might be different categories in your specific country). As a generic rule, the private commercial company license is more expensive, the public sector and education are cheaper, the charity is even cheaper.

The space you are given in total depends on the number of licenses purchased (example if you have a thousand employees, you will purchase 1000 licenses, granting you an initial amount of space per license, note that this space is NOT the space in the personal mysite of every employee, it is an overall space for SharePoint site collections). I believe that there is a basic space even if you have 10 licenses, but in general it is proportionate to the total number of licenses. The amount of space per license does not change if you purchase a top tier license (A5) or a mid tier license (A3).

Once you 'finish' up your allocated space you can purchase extra space. Again the price depends on your location and type of license. I can give you an example in GBP for an education sector org. 1 tb of space was billed 1800 GBP per year. Again, this quote is 2 years old so you should rely on your Microsoft account person or the IT provider that manages the licenses for your organization. I have tried to find out what 1 tb would be for my current org based on online information and I was not able to, you need to contact Microsoft and ask for a quote based on your situation.

As far as I know, Microsoft do not do 'back ups' for you and guarantees the service in case of fault on their end. If you want to add a service that is not provided in the cloud such as back up, you need to search online third party tools to do it for you.

Comment: Thank Susan thats very helpful gives me a rough idea of what to expect. Once we have firmed up our requirements will approach Microsoft,